# Create custom square grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project trying to make something resembling an etch-a-sketch. I have a 780x780px square, and I am trying to get a 16x16 grid, using a series of smaller square divs.

It is on this grid that I have the hover effect. I keep getting a 15x17 grid of square divs because the last square of the row won't fit. I have margins set to 1px and padding set to 0 so I figured that to fit 16 squares on a 780px wide row, it would require me to take into account the margins (15 1px margins) and from there I could divide (780-15) by 16, the number of squares I want.

That isn't working, and the next step of this project is to have a button where the user could input any number of squares for the row/column and have either a larger or smaller squared grid **STILL ON** the 780x780 square. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm pretty stumped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var original = 16;
  for (var y = 0; y < original * original; y++) {
    $(".squares").width((780 - 15) / original);
    $(".squares").height((780 - 17) / original);
    $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo('#main');
  }
  $('.squares').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
    }
  )

});

function gridq() {
  $('.squares').removeClass('hover');
  $('div').remove('.squares');

  var newgrid = prompt("How many squares on each side?");
  var widthscreen = 192;

  if (newgrid > 0) {
    for (var x = 0; x < newgrid * newgrid; x++) {
      $(".squares").width(widthscreen / newgrid);
      $(".squares").height(widthscreen / newgrid);
      $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo('#main');
    }
    $('.squares').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  height: 780px;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: relative;
}
.squares {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=main>
</div>
<button onclick="gridq()">Go Again!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet? Grid initialisation is set in the `grid()` function and then called later when necessary. The width is set dynamically to the 16th square's right side.and the remaining squares fill out as necessary.

```js
var wide = (780 - 15) / 16,
  tall = (780 - 17) / 16; // set the square dimensions. this can be incorporated into the grid() function with 16 replaced by 'original'

function grid(x, y) {
  var original = x,
    y = y;
  $("#main").empty(); // empty and restart
  $("#main").width(wide * (original + 1));

  for (var i = 0; i < original * y; i++) {

    $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo('#main');
  }

  var square = $(".squares");
  square.width(wide);
  square.height(tall);

  var side = square.eq(original - 1).position().left + square.width() + 2; // tighten the #main width
  $("#main").width(side);

  $('.squares').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
    }
  )
}

grid(16, 16); // starting dimension

function gridq() {
  $('.squares').removeClass('hover');
  $('div').remove('.squares');

  var newgrid = prompt("How many squares on each side?");
  var widthscreen = 192;

  if (newgrid > 0) {
    grid(newgrid, newgrid);
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: relative;
}
.squares {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'>
</div>
<button onclick="gridq()">Go Again!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just got beat to it...ill post this as it answers the question slightly differently and I feel is a little cleaner. Also I added in a width and a height prompt.

see the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/tenmilebrenty/pen/mRzYGz)

As a side note...its good practice to make the names of your variables make sense. Also I find that breaking down your code problems into smaller more manageable chunks makes it seem less overwhelming...one step at a time :)

Enjoy and good luck!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //declare the variables at the top of  your functions...it enables us to change them later
  var columnWidthCount = 16;
  var columnHeightCount = 16;
  
  function makeBoxes() {
    //boxcount lets us set how many times we want the for loop to run...when we change the columns/rows later this variable will be updated
    var boxCount = columnWidthCount * columnHeightCount;
  //
    for (var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) { //loop through each box
    //any code you place in here will execute each time we loop around
      $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo('#main');
    }
    //we only want to declare this once so we place it after the loop
    $(".squares").width((780 / columnWidthCount) - 2);
    $(".squares").height((780 / columnHeightCount) - 2);
    $('.squares').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
    );
  }
  //fire the initial function
  makeBoxes();
  // fire function after click
  $('button').on("click", function() {
 
    $('div').remove('.squares');

    var squaresHigh = prompt("How many squares high? (must be a number)");
    var squaresWide = prompt("How many squares wide? (must be a number)");
   //prompt returns a string...use parseInt to turn that number string into an integer
    columnWidthCount = parseInt(squaresWide);
    columnHeightCount = parseInt(squaresHigh);

    makeBoxes();
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  height: 780px;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: relative;
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.squares {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=main>
</div>
<button>Go Again!</button>
```

Comment: I follow this, and I like how clean it is. However, I'm being thrown by the `$(".squares").width((780 / columnWidthCount) - 2);
    $(".squares").height((780 / columnHeightCount) - 2);`. Could you explain the logic behind the calculation? I cannot figure out why "-2" works and would like to know. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helps. That code is setting the width and height of each square. It takes the total width of the container, divides it by how many squares there are in that direction. It subtracts 2 because we have margin set to 1px on all sides. Which is 2px for width and 2px for height. We subtract it so the boxes and the margin equals the width and height of the container...makes sense?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. If I change the CSS, I will be sure to alter the code to compensate. Thanks!